# C# HttpRequestException when doing web calls inside a VM

Tags: c#, wpf, virtual-machine, httprequest, httpclient

I am having a problem with my C# application. I am using Httpclient to make web calls using HttpClient.SendAsync(request). This normally works but when i try to use it in a Virtual machine (VMware) it does not and get "exception thrown 'system.net.http.httprequestexception' in mscorlib.dll".

I hope someone can help me with this. If i need to provide more information, please let me know what u need.

EDIT: i was able to dig a little deeper and i found a more specific error. however, i still have no idea what the cause could be:
[image]

Comment: please post whole exception message . ( The result of Exception.Message and Exception.StackTrace )

Comment: @Arphile i updated the main post.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @Arphile seems that solution worked even though i had tried it before and it didn't. very weird stuff it seems. Thanks for the help

Comment: Write `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls1.2 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls1.1` code before calling making request.